# Flask-Session CORS problem when in incognito mode (private mode)

Tags: python, flask, session, cors

I am facing issues with Flask-Session in relation to CORS while working in incognito mode.

System Operation:
I am developing a chat that is hosted on the client's server (the JS and HTML part), but all Flask functions are on my server. When the user sends the first message, a session (cookie) is created with a user ID. This ID is sent to the Flask server to register the message, among other operations. Remember that this ID is saved to maintain operations such as fetching updated messages, etc.

Code:
This works in normal tabs in Chrome. I have already solved the CORS issue using Flask-CORS and the following lines of code:

**python (flask hosted on my server)**

```
Global:
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True  # Assegure-se de usar HTTPS
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'  # Define a política SameSite para None

Session creation:
@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    session.permanent = True
    session.modified = True
    if 'client_web_id' not in session:
        session['client_web_id'] = random.randint(1000, 9999)

Session after request
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://clientwebsite.com.br')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    return response
```

In normal guides, the session is created and passed normally in the POST via AJAX by the code:

**javascript (hosted on the client):**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myserver.com.br/send_message",
    type: "POST",
    data: { message: message },
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    ...
});
```

**Problem:**
However, in incognito mode, since version 86 of Chrome, third-party cookies are blocked, causing nothing to work as expected.

[image: Image about incognito mode issue:]

I have read several posts but all only talk about the cross-origin problem. As mentioned, it has already been solved, now the problem is only in incognito mode.

**Question:**
The only solution I can think of would be to pass the cookies as a parameter in AJAX, instead of in the header. Would this work? Are there other possible solutions to this problem?